# Picotux alternatives available?

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, i2c, linux

I wanted to use a tiny Linux computer to read data from I²C bus. I knew there was Picotux, and I was thingking about buying one.

[image]

But the website is down, so I guess there's no Picotux anymore. :(

Since Picotux is gone, are there alternatives around, that house a Linux computer in a tiny package, such as Picotux?

I need a tiny package, it should run on batteries and consume little power, and have a I²C or USB bus available. Bonus points if it has WLAN (which Picotux had as an option).

It should be able to run a webserver (a tiny one, not a behemoth as Apache) and RRDtool if possible.

Picotux was available at the now defunct website: http://www.picotux.com/

Comment: That looks awesome! Wish they were still around.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11692/seeking-small-cheap-embedded-pc and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/options-for-a-small-linux-hw-platform

Comment: I've got 5pcs. of Picotux 100 for sale.

Answer (score 4):

The [Digi Connect ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digi_Connect_ME) is a similar device.

> With respect to software development
>   options, in addition to NET+OS, the
>   Digi Connect ME 9210 now also provides
>   a complete Embedded Linux development
>   environment with an Eclipse based IDE.

[image]
<sub>(source: [newark.com](https://www.newark.com/productimages/nio/standard/4734618.jpg))</sub>

[2 MB Flash, 8 MB RAM Ethernet Module for NET+OS -- 94M6849](http://datasheets.globalspec.com/ds/3510/Newarkelement14/246D54E7-48B8-4FCD-B67F-F89F674C088F)

Comment: Does it run Linux?

Comment: The Wikipedia page in the link says yes

Comment: for 400 USD this is quite expensive, compared to picotux...